# Is there a way to view the predicted values against the actual values as a scatterplot in H2O Flow?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, h2o

Is there a quick way in H2O Flow to view a scatterplot of predicted vs actual variables on the Train or Validate data when modelling a continuous target variable?

Or is this only possible by calling a plot in R?

H2O Flow has many useful diagnostics when training a model, but it would be nice to be able to view predicted vs actual on a scatterplot. I can run code in R for this (train the model, use the model to predict on training / validation data, bind predictions to actual, plot predicted vs actual in ggplot), but does Flow offer a quick way to view a diagnostic of this type?